# How to incrementally update changelog?

Tags: spring, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I've generated changelog with

```
java -jar liquibase.jar --changeLogFile="./data/<insert file name>" generateChangeLog
```

I've got a "create table" changelog.

After it I altered table by adding a new column and runned

```
java -jar liquibase.jar --changeLogFile="./data/<insert file name>"
```

generateChangeLog

again. I expected to see incremental log with "create table" and "alter table", but it showing "ChangeLog ...... already exists!".

How to incrementally update ChangeLog?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `generateChangelog` command is used to generate an initial changelog. If you want to append to a changelog you use the `diffChangelog` command.

Comment: Can I ask you to provide usage example of `diffChangelog`? Thank you.

Comment: I Googled it and it seems, that it's for diffs between 2 different databases, not to update changelog file, isn't it?

Comment: See this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002568/how-to-use-liquibase-diffchangelog-with-the-current-changelog-as-reference-to-g